# Executing code in __init__

Tags: python, class, init

I'm trying to untar xz/bx2/gz files in the **init** section of my class. I'm using the following code :

```
class myClass(object):
def __init__(self, *args):
    for i in args:
        try:
            f = tarfile.open(i)
            print("Extracting ", i)
            f.extractall()
            f.close()
        except tarfile.ReadError:
            print("File not a tarball, or any of .xz/.bz2/.gz archives.")
            exit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    <???>
```

The only problem here is, I'm not sure what to call after "**main**", in order to initialize and run the **init** method. I've just started out, and am a bit unclear.

If I'm to write a function named unpack() which does the untarring rather than putting it under **init**, i know i can do something like :

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    start = myClass()
    start.unpack()
```

Since I want to do the unpacking in **init** itself, how would I do it in this case ?

Edit:

Sorry in case I'm not clear, I'm trying to run this script from the command line as :

```
# python script.py file1.tar.bz2 file2.tar.bz2 file3.tar.bz2
```

So the *args should be populated with the file names, and hence the code to extract it should run, atleast from what I know.

Thank you,

Comment: You're not passing any arguments to `__init__` or rather to the `myClass()` call so the loop never executes... what do you expect a loop over an empty list to do?

Comment: Okay, regarding the edit - go read [this](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/interpreter.html#argument-passing) and [this](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects). You seem to have a vague idea what you're doing but at the same time don't grasp some very basic concepts...

Comment: There is absolutely no need to make this a class.

Answer (score 1):

You just call myClass() :

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    start = myClass(sys.argv)
```

Comment: I think this is the answer the OP wanted, but I think it should probably be said that doing your work in the `__init__` method is probably a bad idea. Either move it to a method, or just make a function that does the work directly (classes are not necessary for every problem in Python).

Comment: Yes, i understand Classes are not necessary. This was just a part of learning.. I have it working without classes..